# Love2D how to zoom out map?

Tags: lua, love2d

I've set up a basic map with Tiled, imported it with STI library (https://github.com/karai17/Simple-Tiled-Implementation) and everything looks in place.

How can i get a zoom-out feature now? I can kinda zoom in using scalex and scaley and i tried the same procedure to zoom out.

However, if i set i.e. scalex = 0.5, scaley = 0.5 the map actually scales in size but it only fit 1/4 the screen size, and the remaining 3/4 are just black space.

Answer (score 1):

This code just uses individual tile images that must each be 100x100 px. The zoom still needs a bit of tweaking.

```
function love.load()

  tileImage = love.graphics.newImage("tileImage.png") --tile size is currently 100x100px
  tileSize = 100

  mapLength,mapHeight = 20,10
  zoom, zoomSpeed = 0.3, 0.05
  cameraX,cameraY = 1,1
  cameraSpeed = 0.1
  zoomOffset = 0.01

  map = {}

  for x = 0,mapLength+1 do
    map[x] = {}

    for y = 0,mapHeight+1 do

      map[x][y] = {tileImage}

    end
  end



end

function love.draw()

  for x=1,mapLength do
    for y=1, mapHeight do
        love.graphics.draw(map[x][y][1],applyScrollX(x),applyScrollY(y),0,zoom,zoom)
    end
  end

end

function love.update()

  print(zoom..", "..cameraX..", "..cameraY)

  if love.keyboard.isDown('w') then cameraY = cameraY + cameraSpeed end
  if love.keyboard.isDown('a') then cameraX = cameraX + cameraSpeed end
  if love.keyboard.isDown('s') then cameraY = cameraY - cameraSpeed end
  if love.keyboard.isDown('d') then cameraX = cameraX - cameraSpeed end

  function love.wheelmoved(x, y)
    if y > 0 then
        zoom = zoom + zoomSpeed 
    cameraX,cameraY = cameraX - zoomOffset, cameraY - zoomOffset
    elseif y < 0 then
        zoom = zoom - zoomSpeed 
    cameraX,cameraY = cameraX + zoomOffset, cameraY + zoomOffset
    end
end

end

function applyScrollX(num) --num is x position in tiles

  return num*zoom*tileSize+(cameraX*tileSize)

end

function applyScrollY(num)

  return num*zoom*tileSize+(cameraY*tileSize)

end
```